# Is it some way in Kivy to call different action on touch many different lines

Tags: kivy, touch, line

is it some way to call different action on touch this many different lines? ?

```
for i in range(20):
    self.root.ids.card.canvas.after.add(Line(points=[100 * i,200,100 * i,800]))
```

Comment: Undoubtedly yes, but I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I draw a graph using lines (90 pieces). After clicking on the line, I want to display the value above it.

Comment: I think the way to approach this is: forget about the existence of the Line, it's just something you happen to be drawing. What you actually want to do is turn your clicks into data that you display in a Label. The basic logic flow will be something like: 1) take the touch input, 2) calculate where the touch is in relation to your line points, 3) display a Label widget somewhere near the touch with the text you desire

Comment: OK, thank for show the way. It's the way to go. I assumed there is an on_release option 
 to shapes objects (not all canvas) in Kivy.